# clojure way for C#/java event, eventlisteners

Tags: clojure

Im from C#, and my clojure expirience is about two weeks.
I want track some object and receive notifications from it.
In C#  im using events. 
Any clojure best practices for this problem?

For example:

service-controller.clj

```
(def shared-state)
(defn start-watch [x]
 ;; add object to watch in shared state
    )

(loop blah blah
 ;; check all objects in shared state and in some cases delete object, change object
 recur  )
```

in another file, i want to add listeners for service-controller shared state.
engine.clj
    (add-listener service-controller/shared-state fn blah)

```
(service-controller/start-watch x)
```

I found agent and add-watch, its ok, but how i can modify vector inside agent?

Answer (score 1):

`send` and `send-off` are used to alter agent state.  The [documentation](http://clojure.org/agents%20documentation) has more details, but basically you call `send` with a function that computes the new state.